# start animation render at a negative frame

Tags: rendering, animation, keyframes, timeline

A very useful simple feature that would solve many problems. Is there a way to render my animation starting at frame -50? I know there is an option in the settings "allow negative frames" but that works only for a preview. Thank you.

Comment: If you are using keyframes, select them all in the dopesheet editor and press G 50 to slide all of the keyframes. But, please [edit] your question and explain why do you need to do this.

Comment: I have multiple particle systems baked that start at a specific frame in the project. I need to offset only the first part of the animation, the second half needs to stay as is (this part has all the baked particles). I mean, I can rebake and redo everything but the project is complex and negative frame render would be one-click thing. Don't understand why the rendering can't be set like that.